# Imported module but still need to use full name

Tags: python, pyqt

I've been able to successfully import QtWidgets from PyQt5 and this works fine in code however if I don't use the full QtWidgets name in the call I get an error. Below works...

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import  QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Yet if do...

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import  QtWidgets

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

I get ...

NameError: name 'QApplication' is not defined

Comment: If you think that `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets` should enable you to refer to things without using `QtWidgets.whatever`, you don't understand how Python imports work.  Take a look at [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: What seems to be the problem? In both your examples you need `QtWidgets` because that is the only namspace Python is currently aware of. If you want your desired behavior use `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication`

Comment: This looks to of solved the import problem but now I'm getting This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"
in "". on that same line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your misunderstanding how Python `import` statements work. When importing a module in Python, only the module directly imported is include in the local symbol table.

Thus, if you have not directly imported a name, it cannot be used as a standalone identifier in the current namespace. If you want this behavior, directly import the `QApplication` name from the `QtWidgets` namespace:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
```

Answer (score 0):

Import modules like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Comment: No, don't use wildcard imports. In more complex projects they will make it hard to trace the origin of imports.