# Why cant python find a class in my module?

Tags: python, unit-testing, import

I am writing a simple python package with some unit tests:

```
goal_light:
horn.py  __init__.py

tests:
context.py  horn_test.py  __init__.py
```

horn.py:

```
class Horn:
    def __init__():
        pass
```

context.py:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

import goal_light
```

horn_test.py:

```
from .context import goal_light

def test_construct_horn():
    horn = goal_light.Horn()
```

Running the tests gets me:

```
$ py.test
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-2.8.7, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/peter/example, inifile: 
collected 1 items 

tests/horn_test.py F

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_____________________________ test_construct_horn ______________________________

    def test_construct_horn():
>       horn = goal_light.Horn()
E    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Horn'

tests/horn_test.py:4: AttributeError
=========================== 1 failed in 0.02 seconds ===========================
```

I'm clearly running afoul of something in

http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

but I'm not sure what.

This has been flagged as a duplicate of

[Imported module but still need to use full name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083372)

But I am clearly using the full name `goal_light.Horn` as suggested in that post when instatiating the class. What am I missing?

Comment: You have to import `goal_light.horn` in `context`. Or, to make it work as written, in `__init__` in `goal_light` use `from goal_light.horn import Horn`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imported module but still need to use full name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083372/imported-module-but-still-need-to-use-full-name)